# List the elements in the set $C'$ union $A'$. Is this approach correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let
$$U = \{q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z\}\text,$$
$$A = \{q, s, u, w, y\}\text,$$
$$C = \{v, w, x, y, z\}\text.$$

List the elements in the set $C'$ union $A'$.

$$C' \cup A'\\
=(C \cap A)'\\
=\{w, y\}'\\
= \{q, r, s, t, u, v, x, z\}$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! Your calculations are correct. Congrats!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution strategy is perfectly valid (it uses one of DeMorgan's laws, which states that $A'\cup B' = (A\cap B)'$, exactly as you have written it). If you wanted another solution strategy, you could also calculate $C' \cup A'$ in the following way

$$C' = \{q,r,s,t,u\}\\
A' = \{r,t,v,x,z\}\\
C'\cup A' = \{q,r,s,t,u,v,x,z\}$$